# Finding texts in between 2 words when there's more than 2 same words

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, find

I'm trying to get a text in between 2 words. I'm having a trouble to get the text when there's 2 exact same word. In this case "Edition". I have following texts in A column.

```
Abc Authentic Desktop 2022 Enterprise Edition Concurrent Users
Abc DiffMerge 2022 Professional Edition Named Users
Abc Flow Server 2022 Advanced Edition 2 Core One Year
Upgrade From Abc XML 2004 Professional Edition To Abc XML 2022 Enterprise Edition Concurrent Users
```

I want to extract the Edition from these product names like below.

```
Enterprise Edition
Professional Edition
Advanced Edition
Enterprise Edition
```

If I use this formula below, it works except the last one which has 2 Editions in the string.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("2022",A1)+5,FIND("Edition ",A1)+2-FIND("2022",A1))
```

Also I want to get the words after Edition (2nd Edition for the 4th item).
Can you suggest how to write the formula to use the 2nd Edition in the string?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows Excel 2013+ with the function, you can use:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[.='Edition'][last()]/preceding::*[1]") & " Edition"
```

To extract the **last** Edition

[image]

A variation on the above, but requiring Windows Office 365 in this implementation, to return the last edition in the string and everything after:

```
=LET(x,"<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>",
     y,FILTERXML(x,"//s[.='Edition'][last()]/preceding::*[1]"),
     z, FILTERXML(x,"//s[.='Edition'][last()]/preceding::*[1]/following-sibling::*"),
     TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,y,z))
```

[image]

As pointed out by @JvdV, this second formula can be simplified to using a single `FILTERXML` call by using a different `xPath` argument to:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[following::*[2]='Edition'][last()]/following::*"))
```

It still requires `TEXTJOIN` which, if I recall correctly, did not appear until Excel 2019.

***EDIT:***
It seems the requirements description were initially incomplete.  What the OP really wants is to have

- The two words starting with the word before `Edition` in `B1`
- All the words following `Edition` in `C1`

That being the case, the formulas are:

```
B1:  =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[.='Edition'][last()]/preceding::*[2]/following::*[position()<3]"))

C1:  =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",UNICHAR(8203)&"(")," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[.='Edition'][last()]/following::*"))
```

[image]

*Note the nested `SUBSTITUTE` function in the `C1` formula. By inserting a non-printing character (ZWSP) we fool the function into treating `(1)` as a text string, instead of then number `-1`, thereby preserving the parentheses in the output*

Comment: Very nice +. If you'd allow me, but maybe the 2nd formula can be formulated as: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE("a "&A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[following::*[2]='Edition'][last()]/following::*"))`, which would avoid a nested `FILTERXML()` operation.

Comment: @JvdV Very very nice.  I fiddled with the xPath last night to try to eliminate the nested operation, but it was getting late and I couldn't develop it.

Comment: @JvdV why `"a "&A1` instead of just `A1` in the `SUBSTITUTE` function?

Comment: I had it there in case OP would have a string like 'Enterprise Edition Concurrent Users'. It would only have one sibling in front of 'Edition', meaning it would throw an error. Though not likely, it's basically just to prevent errors ;)

Comment: @JvdV Ah, very good. I didn't consider that the beginning of the string was important since his "working for one Edition" code is looking for a string of numbers before the desired string.

Comment: How do I get words after Editions such as "Concurrent Users" and "Named Users"? I tried to figure it out but I gave up.

Comment: @ToshiW  What happened when you tried one of the two formulas I posted that showed how to do that?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld The first formula worked and shows 'Enterprise Edition'. The last formula, it shows 'Enterprise Edition Concurrent Users -1' with -1 at the end. I want to get only 'Concurrent Users'.

Comment: @ToshiW I have no idea where the `-1` is coming from as I don't see it in your data or in the formula.  And you mentioned *I want to get the words after ...*. So if you have strings after that you do NOT want returned, you will need to define clearly what you mean by *the words after ...*

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I apologize for the confusion. In A1 cell I have "Upgrade from Authentic 2010 Professional Edition to Authentic 2022 Enterprise Edition Concurrent Users (1)", in B1 I want "Enterprise Edition" and C1 "Concurrent Users (1)". I got B1 part, but not C1 cell.

Comment: @ToshiW Always better to show full requirements and representative data initially. In any event, I think the last edit should return what you are looking for.